# Comparing variables of with a vector of solutions

Tags: r, purrr

I am facing the following problem. I have a test with multiple questions and the answers of the subjects are recorded in the variables Q1 to Q3 (in reality I have many more questions)

```
test <- tibble(
  Q1 = c(4, 5, 6), 
  Q2 = c(3, 2, 1),  
  Q3 = c(4, 1, 3))
```

I put the correct answers for questions 1, 2 and 3 in a vector

```
correct_answers <- c(4,2,3)
```

And now I to create a new variable that counts the number of correct answers for each subject.  My guess is that it works with a map2 function and, but I could not figure out how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can create a logical matrix in `base R` and then do the `rowSums` to count the number of correct answers

```
test$newCol <- rowSums(test == correct_answers[col(test)])
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, using `map2` with `reduce` to create a 'newCol' in the dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
      mutate(newCol = map2(., correct_answers, `==`) %>% 
                       reduce(`+`))
```

Answer (score 5):

Does this work?

```
library(purrr)
test %>% 
  map_dbl(~sum(.x%in%correct_answers))
```

Answer (score 5):

We could use `mapply` and then do `rowSums`

```
df$ans <- rowSums(mapply(`==`, test, correct_answers))
```

---

With `map2` it could be something like

```
library(purrr)
map2(test, correct_answers, function(x, y) sum(x == y))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
rowSums(apply(test, 2, `==`, correct_answers))
```

Answer (score 1):

Many good answers above already. Just to clarify, your post has been interpreted in two different ways.

If your vector `correct_answers` has the one correct answer per question (ie correct Q1 answer is 4 and only 4). Then, sticking with `purrr` you could pick this answer:

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
      mutate(newCol = map2(., correct_answers, `==`) %>% 
                       reduce(`+`))
```

If you're saying that `correct_answers` has correct answers for any question, then this one would be the one:

```
library(purrr)
test %>% 
  map_dbl(~sum(.x%in%correct_answers))
```

Comment: @RonakShah, yes I upvoted them! It's just that there are four different answers to two different questions... I'll edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this a perfect use case for `?sweep()` from base R -

```
test$n_correct <- rowSums(sweep(test, 2, correct_answers, "=="))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     Q1    Q2    Q3 n_correct
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     4     3     4         1
2     5     2     1         1
3     6     1     3         1
```